# How to.. the middle div of three ever on center and if the navigator are resized

Tags: css, html

Sorry about my english.

Please, i have a problem with divs, i have 3 divs "with image" horizontally, the images have to be together.

Here is the default view, if the screen is large enough.
[image: Start]

If the navigator are resized i lost center with the #div2. The #div1 are aligned to the left, that is not i need.
[image: Problem]

What i need is the #div2 stay on center, but i don't know to do that. #div1 and #div3 are outside of the navigator, no one div can be resized, are a fixed size.
[image: What i want]

The html code:

```
<body id="body">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="baseLeftBg">
        </div>
        <div id="baseContent">
        </div>
        <div id="baseRightBg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS code:

```
#body {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    float: inherit;
}

#wrap { 
    width: 1484px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

#baseLeftBg {
    margin-top: 60px;
    background: #CDCDCD;
    width: 286px;
    height: 776px;
    float: left;
}

#baseContent {
    margin-top: 60px;
    background: #A7A7A7;
    width: 911px;
    height: 776px;
    float: left;
}

#baseRightBg {
    margin-top: 60px;
    background: #CDCDCD;
    width: 286px;
    height: 776px;
    float: left;
}
```

How i can do that?

Link to Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/murb83/BChLs/

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you would like the middle div fixed and the left and right flexible?

Comment: the three divs have to be together, but if i resize the screen the middle div have to be forever on the middle, the others can go first outside of navigator

Comment: is like if the anchor point of all are on the center of the #div2. I hope I explained well.

Comment: I add on the bottom of the question the jsFiddle link to se the code in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the solution without JS works ok for me at the moment...

```
#wrap { 
    margin-top: 5%; 
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -742px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1484px;
    height: 776px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making  text-align center for wrapper will be helpful. This will show the elements in center.

```
#wrap { 
    width: 1484px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: thanks! but the problem persist #div1 doesn't go out of the navigator. Do the same like my second image on top. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try making it dynamic, with percentages like:

```
#baseLeftBg {
    ..
    width: 20%;
    ..
}

#baseContent {
    ..
    width: 60%;
    ..
}

#baseRightBg {
    ..
    width: 20%;
    ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solution could be using absolute positioning like this:

```
#wrap {
..
position:relative;
..
}

#baseLeftBg {
margin-top: 60px;
background: #CDCDCD;
width: 286px;
height: 776px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}

#baseContent {
margin-top: 60px;
background: #A7A7A7;
width: 911px;
height: 776px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}

#baseRightBg {
margin-top: 60px;
background: #CDCDCD;
width: 286px;
height: 776px;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn't work, the divs have to be together but the #div2 have to maintain on the middle. I do a Fiddle of the codes: [lick](http://jsfiddle.net/murb83/Wue57/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider using Javascript for solving your problem?
You should have a container larger as much as you want containing your three divs and with javascript, based on the screen width, you should set the left margin (obviously it could be a negative number).

Then, with JS, you can also handle the event on screen resize for "adjust" the left margin

Comment: Hi, thanks! I don't know to use Javascript, but i will try to find information to learn how to do it.

Comment: #wrap { 
    width: 1484px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that with jsQuery.

HTML

```
<body id="body">
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="baseLeftBg">
        </div>
        <div id="baseContent">
        </div>
        <div id="baseRightBg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>​
```

CSS

```
#body {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    float: inherit;
}

#wrap { 
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}

#baseLeftBg {
    background: #CDCDCD;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}

#baseContent {
    background: #A7A7A7;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}

#baseRightBg {
    background: #CDCDCD;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}​
```

JSQuery

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('#wrap').css({
    position:'absolute',
    left: ($(window).width() - $('#wrap').outerWidth())/2,
    top: ($(window).height() - $('#wrap').outerHeight())/2
  });
});

// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();

var $scrollingDiv = $("#wrap");
     $(window).scroll(function(){            
        $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, 500, 'easeInOutSine' );            
     });
```

See in action: http://jsfiddle.net/murb83/BChLs/

Comment: I found a problem with that. If i do the browser smaller than the web site, i can't scroll correctly in any direction, the script is constantly centering the website.. and i can't see the left part of website too.